# Windows для одного приложения

Tags: windows

На компьютере  работают только 2 приложения - *MSDE 2000* и его клиентская часть.

Как при загрузке *Windows* исключить возможность работы оператора непосредственно с *ОС* (*Windows XP*), т.е. оператор может пользоваться только клиентским приложением?

Answer (score 4):

В реестре находите ключик `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` и параметру `Shell` указываете путь к своей программе которую надо запустить вместо `Explorer.exe`.
В результате, рабочего стола с кнопкой пуск не будет, будет запускаться Ваше приложение. Если пользователь закроет Ваше приложение, произойдет выход из сеанса/завершение работы.

В большинстве случаев - это оптимальное решение.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую. Как я понял, в клиентском приложении мне надо дописать процедуру, восстанавливающую реестр?

Comment: По желанию и надобности.

Comment: Маленькая поправка. Лучше писать в ветку HKCU, нежели в HKLM. В таком случае можно будет завести пользователя, который будет логинится сразу в программу, и админа с полноценным рабочим столом.

Answer (score 2):

Можно поступить по садистски хитро - в качестве оболочки прописать нужное приложение. То есть вместо explorer.exe будет запускаться, к примеру, msdn.exe:

Идем в regedit по пути 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESOFTWAREMicrosoftWindowsCurrentVersionWinlogon

и меняем параметр Shell на путь к нужной программе.

и дополнительно в аналогичной ветке:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESOFTWAREMicrosoftWindows NTCurrentVersionWinlogon

проделываем тот же финт.

Можно сделать файлы реестра, включающие и отключающие данную фишку. К примеру, содержимое файла реестра, включающее explorer в качестве оболочки:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"Shell"="c:\\windows\\explorer.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"Shell"="c:\\windows\\explorer.exe"
```

Точно так же можно создать файл реестра для запуска своей программы:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"Shell"="c:\\Program Files\\OurProgram\\program.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"Shell"="c:\\Program Files\\OurProgram\\program.exe"
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую. Как я понял, в клиентском приложении мне надо дописать процедуру, восстанавливающую реестр?

Comment: Можно и так. Кстати, действительно, выше KoVadim подсказал верную идею - не менять настройку на уровне машины, а лучше сменить на уровне пользователя. То есть ветвь реестра HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE сменить на HKEY_CURRENT_USER. Тогда у отдельного пользователя будет настроена в качестве оболочки его программа, остальные же работать будут в старом режиме - с explorer и рабочим столом.

Answer (score 0):

Можно ограничить пользователя политиками: [Использование редактора групповой политики для управления политикой локальных компьютеров в Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307882/).

Еще для Windows XP была утилита от Microsoft - SteadyState, которая позволяла ограничивать пользователя XP самыми разными способами.

P.S. Вообще это вопрос на [РутКод](http://admin.hashcode.ru).